# BackboneJS - fetching collections from model

Tags: json, backbone.js

I have a JSON file which basically looks like this:

```
[
 {
   "First" : [...]
 },

 {
   "Second" : [...]
 },

 {
   "Third" : [...]
 },
]
```

In my router i have:

```
this.totalCollection = new TotalCollection();
this.totalView = new TotalView({el:'#subContent', collection:this.totalCollection});

this.totalCollection.fetch({success: function(collection) {
   self.totalView.collection=collection;
   self.totalView.render();
}});
```

Now i have my Backbone Model:

```
define([
 "jquery",
 "backbone"
],

function($, Backbone) {
var TotalModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: "/TotalCollection.json",

    initialize: function( opts ){
        this.first = new First();
        this.second = new Second();
        this.third = new Third();

        this.on( "change", this.fetchCollections, this );
    },

      fetchCollections: function(){
        this.first.reset( this.get( "First" ) );
        this.second.reset( this.get( "Second" ) );
        this.third.reset( this.get( "Third" ) );
      }
});

return TotalModel;
});
```

and my in my Backbone View i try to render the collection(s):

```
render: function() {
    $(this.el).html(this.template(this.collection.toJSON()));
    return this;
}
```

But I get the Error "First is not defined" - whats the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

Have you actually defined a variable 'First', 'Second' and 'Third'? Based on what you're showing here, there is nothing with that name. One would expect you to have a couple lines like..

```
var First = Backbone.Collection.extend({});
var Second = Backbone.Collection.extend({});
var Third = Backbone.Collection.extend({});
```

However you haven't provided anything like that, so my first assumption is that you just haven't defined it.

Per comments, this may be more what you need:

```
render: function() {
    $(this.el).html(this.template({collection: this.collection.toJSON())});
    return this;
}
```

Then..

```
{{#each collection}}
    {{#each First}}
        /*---*/
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: ah ok, thats right :-) So should that be in the Model too? and should there be something inside the curly brackets { } ?

Comment: Nothing should really be necessary inside of the curlies unless you're doing something special for each - otherwise you could just as easily say `this.first = new Backbone.Collection()` and it'd work just as well.

Comment: Ok great! Now I don't get any errors. So far so good, but still no data :s I added my fetch() to my question. Maybe there is something wrong with that?

Comment: I think your best friend here would be lots of console.log statements to track the progress of data to your view. Breakpoints too - I'd set one on your render to see what data you have available.. The toJSON won't really understand how to unwrap the collections, so you may need to do some manual work there too. Sorry, gotta go to sleep considering is 430am :)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help anyway! Did not expect it would be sooo difficult just to display some simple collections/json data in a view :-/

Comment: Ok when I do `console.log(this.collection)` in the render function in my view I get "child {length: 4, models: Array[4], _byId: Object, _events: Object, constructor: function…}" - the collections with its content are available, but I dont know how to display them

Comment: Does it maybe have to do that I'm using Handlebars? `{{#each First}}<li><a href="{{this.url}}">{{this.name}}</a></li>{{/each}`, this is for each collection, so i have four of these, always with a different each -> First, Second etc

Comment: OK - I just realized you have a TotalCollection as well as a TotalModel. Chances are you need to do something more like my edit.